# Entity Framework and adding a reference / entry to a lookup table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, lookup

I have a project where I use a lookup table to link two tables together:

```
Day         WeatherLookUp       Weather
---         -------------       -------    
ID (PK) --> DayID            |- ID (PK)
            WeatherID    <---|  Description
```

This allows me to specify multiple weather conditions for a day.

I can read from this without any issues but my problem is when I come to insert a link between the Day and the Weather table. I created the WeatherLookup table's two columns as the compound primary key of the table and as a result EF doesn't allow me to do a direct insert into the WeatherLookup table.

I had thought I just needed to add a Weather entry like this:

```
myDay.Weather.Add(new Weather { ID = 2 } );
```

...but EF thinks I'm trying to add a new weather type.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't work out what, do I need to be using `Attach()` in some way?

Comment: Yes, you need to use `Attach`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to attach the `Weather` entity to the context in order to tell EF that it already exists in the database and doesn't need to be inserted:

```
var weather = new Weather { ID = 2 };
context.Weather.Attach(weather);
myDay.Weather.Add(weather);
```

Alternatively you can load the entity from the database (which will attach it implicitly to the context):

```
var weather = context.Weather.Find(2);
myDay.Weather.Add(weather);
```

Comment: +1 Perfect, was having this issue myself then started loading the entities so they were in the context, but Attach is a much better route as it doesn't require additional queries on the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assiociate the "Weather" with the "WeatherLookUp" not only using the ID.

something like this:

```
Weather weather = new Weather();
weather.Description = "hi";


WeatherLookUp lookup = new WeatherLookUp ();
lookup.Weather = weather;

myDay.Weather.add(Weather);
myDay.WeatherLookUp.add(lookup);
myDay.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I can't create an instance of WeatherLookUp as the DbContext doesn't expose it, only Day and a Weather are visible.

Comment: It's not being exposed because it doesn't have a PK, only FK.
you can create a pk with auto increment, and you will be able to see it.

Comment: Thanks, I can change the db design to add an auto increment column but I was hoping there would be another way round this. Seems odd that EF doesn't cope well with compound keys in this situation.

Comment: yes, this is really weird but all tables with EF needs to have a PK, as far as I know.